# Можно ли изменить стиль <input> и <textarea> в js

Tags: javascript, css, input, textarea

Есть форма, в ней "инпуты", с ними "текстарея", у этих ребят класс .style-animation. Написала пару строчек, чтоб по событиям **onfocus** и **onblur** менялся цвет и размер. Как заставить этот код работать?

```
var stAnm = document.getElementsByClassName('style-animation');
stAnm.addEventListener('focus',onEvent('200px','#fff'));
stAnm.addEventListener('blur',onEvent('100%','rgba(240, 255, 240, 0.65)'));

function onEvent(height,color){
   this.style.height=height;
   this.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
```

Вроде бы все норм, но не работает. Знаю, что желаемое можно и на ccs задать, однако очень хочется на джс. 
З.Ы. может проблема кроется в this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас две ошибки в коде:

1) `stAnm.addEventListener` не будет работать по скольку `stAnm` массив выбранных элементов с текущим классом, смотрите работу [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

2) `this` не будет виден в функции `callback`, его нужно передать явно.

Вот уже рабочий код с исправлением этих ошибок:

```html
<input type="text" name="anim1" value="anim1" class="style-animation" />
<input type="text" name="anim2" value="anim2" class="style-animation" />
<input type="text" name="anim3" value="anim3" class="style-animation" />
<script>
var stAnm = document.getElementsByClassName('style-animation');

for(var i=0;i<stAnm.length;i++){
    stAnm[i].addEventListener('focus',function(){onEvent(this,'200px','#fff')});
    stAnm[i].addEventListener('blur',function(){onEvent(this, '100%','rgba(240, 255, 240, 0.65)')});
}



function onEvent(elem,height,color){
   elem.style.height=height;
   elem.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `var _this = this;` не лишнее ?)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Ну в принципе здесь можно задать и так `function(){onEvent(this,'200px','#fff')}`